# web api Cross-origin resource sharing

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue while working with web api.when i am consuming web api service getting Cross-origin resource sharing problem.

Actullay i developed web api application and hosted in iis and then i need to consume the service in mvc application  using angularjs.

here is the Actulla problem started,  httppost,httpget working properly.
but [httpput,httpdelete] not working.

Comment: This is not a proper question. See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article - [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

1. In Visual Studio Package Manager Console run:

   Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. Then in **WebApiConfig.Register** method call `config.EnableCors();`

This will enable CORS globally.You can also do it per controller, just read through the article and you will learn different ways this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in the `<system.webServer>` section in the web config of the API project..

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: i have tried this but this is not working. httpdelete and httpput not working